# Micromax canvas juice 3 plus q394 reboots after every 5 minutes of use

Tags: reboot

Im using Micromax canvas juice 3 plus q394 from long time but from few months it overheats and restarts consistently every five minutes of use, i used all hibernate apps as well as memory, cache cleaners app but none of worked if anyone know how to solve this problem please your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple causes of your android's random behavior. I am listing some of then with solution.

1. In most cases, random restarts are caused by a poor quality app. Try uninstalling apps you don’t use. Be sure the apps you do use are reliable, especially the apps that handle email or text messaging.
2. If you disabled apps that are required to run the Android OS, it may be causing your restarting issue. Have a look under “Settings” > “Applications” and swipe over to the list of apps that are “Turned Off” or “Disabled” and enable any apps that may be needed for your device to function properly.
3. Many Android devices are designed to shut off automatically if they become too hot. If you are trying to use 4G, GPS, and the screen is set to the brightest setting, it might restart itself or shut down. Try to take it easy and maybe disable features you don’t need.
4. Loose Battery is also one of the issues.The most common reason for this is the rear cover has become slightly bent and is no longer holding the battery into place. Another reason is the gold battery connectors are bent out of shape. Over time, the connectors may get worn down.
5. Sometimes the Android system software gets corrupted. If you are using a custom Android ROM, try a different version of the ROM or another type of ROM altogether. If you’re not using a custom ROM, your only option may be to try a factory reset of the device.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response 1. I Uninstalled those app which I'm not using already no difference 2. only android service is disabled due to ads 3. phone is not 4g GPS never turned on because im not using but overheats when playing clash of clans 4. Battery is non removeable 5. using the stock rom from 2 years no modification at all factory reset i will try.

Comment: Yes, and do take a backup before you do factory reset.

Comment: I create a backup on my pc but after factory reset the problem not solved it seems to be rom problem i think i should flash stock rom with mtk tool kit through pc but i want to why we untick preloader in mtk toolkit before flash a rom to mtk devices.